# Cannot download the image programmatically by Java

Tags: java, image

I am trying to download an image from the below URL but it always returns HTML. 
Do you know how to download it by java? The below code can download successfully other URL like (http://example.com/img/abc.jpg)

URL
    https://www.ttbonline.gov/colasonline/publicViewAttachment.do?filename=Sankaty%20Body.JPG&filetype=l

Code

```
private static void getImages(String src) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(src);
    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    FileUtils.copyURLToFile(
            url,
            new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\output\\img.jpeg"),
            10000,
            10000);
    in.close();

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your URL response data depended on cookies and authentication method. You could read more about that [here](https://github.com/js-cookie/java-cookie) and [here](https://www.google.co.jp/search?ei=S8VjXKqOF4_j-Aab-aXQCg&q=java%20authentication%20to%20server&oq=java%20authentication%20to%20server&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30.57247.62605..63341...7.0..0.142.1678.2j13......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i203j33i160j0i8i13i30j33i22i29i30j0i13i30.5wDzAAAE-kc). Edit:
This is the page I get when connect your link by a web browser. [![Image capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibVHN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibV

Comment: It is public url and I can view it on web browser without any authentication.

Comment: Are you sure? I can not. Please check it again.

Comment: @TrầnĐứcTâm: you can check it here. https://www.ttbonline.gov/colasonline/publicViewAttachment.do?filename=Sankaty%20Body.JPG&filetype=l

Comment: Uhm. Should I come to his home and help him? Mr.@gpasch? StackOverflow display answer button but not solution button. I showed him his problem and reference to read. Show me the rules I missing here.

Comment: I have double-checked, the provided URL needs permission to render and show image.